# How to redirect output from $host.ui.writeline in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am using a compiled cmdlet that invokes $host.ui.writeline. I would like to redirect this output, but what I have tried so far has not worked. I do not have the option of editing the cmdlet since it is a compiled binary.

```
$host.ui.writeline("test") > $output
$host.ui.writeline("test") *> $output
```

Is it possible to redirect this output to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the output to a textfile and then read the textfile to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`$host.ui.WriteLine()` writes to the host process (i.e. the PowerShell console), just like `Write-Host` does.